# System function to make some ICMP activity

Tags: c, network-programming, ping, icmp

which system command should I use to make some ICMP activity? I tried to use system("ping www.google.com");, but it looks like program does not read further code after that.

Or how to make it read after system("ping www.google.com");?

For example:

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <stdlib.h>
int main() {

    system("ping www.google.com");
    printf("\ncheck");
}
```

outputs `PING www.google.com (173.194.78.105) 56(84) bytes of data` (no check) and I need to stop the program myself afterwards

Comment: Maybe "ping -c 1 ..."?

Comment: it says `ping: bad number of packets to transmit` if I do `ping -c`

Comment: Which OS? On Linux "ping -c 1 www.google.com" works. On windows it will be "ping -n 1 www.google.com"

Comment: And looks like you forgot "1" after "-c"

Comment: well it still does not printf `check`, but yes, it works with 1

Comment: weird. for me it ok. http://pastebin.com/EsME63QJ . as you can see it prints "check" in one line with "root@localhost", maybe you just didnt notice it?

Comment: I am using QEMU. It seems like the program is runnig, cause I need to exit from program myself, I do not have bash otherwise

Comment: Add a `flush(stdout);` after the `printf()`.

Comment: used fflush, nothing changed, just flush does not work